# How to find minimum L such that k given segments with length L could cover n given points?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

*There are n points on the x-axis, each with an integer coordinate in the range [0, n^3
]. We can cover these points with k segments, each of length L (a segment can cover all the points within it, including the endpoints). **Given k and n, how to find the minimum L in O(nlogn) time?***

I've thought that **if n<=k, then L ->0**, but when n>k, things start to be complicated, hope you could help me out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a working algorithm with higher complexity than `O(n log n)` that you're trying to optimize?

Comment: Hello, please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do a binary search on `L`. Assume there's a magic function `check(L)` that returns whether we can cover the points with segments of length `L`, we use binary search to find the minumum `L` such that `check(L)` returns true.

Then, let's implement that magic function. We can place our segments greedily: find the leftmost not covered point, and place a segment so its left endpoint is at that point. Repeat this `k` times, and check if all `n` points have been covered.

Binary search calls `check(L)` `O(log n)` times, each call to `check(L)` takes `O(n)` if we have an order list of points (just scan the array from left to right), in total this is `O(n log n)`. Since the list of points don't change, we can pre-sort the list, which also takes `O(n log n)` time. So the time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Crystal clear, many thanks!

Comment: @Sakura You're welcome! Mind accepting the answer? :)